# Preserving the punctuation after converting it to pig latin

Tags: java, regex, recursion

Currently, I am able to translate an English word to pig latin. My lab assignment says that punctuation occurring before the word should be removed, stored, and prepended to the piglatinized word. Punctuation occurring after the word should be removed, stored, and appended to the piglatinized word. Any punctuation that is in the middle of the word is to be treated as a regular letter.

For example:

- what? -> atwhay?
- Oh!!! -> Ohway!!!
- "hello" -> "ellohay"
- don't -> on'tday
- "pell-mell" -> "ell-mellpay”

This is what I have right now to find and store the punctuations:

```java
public static final String punct = ",./;:'\"?<>[]{}|`~!@#$%^&*()";

String startPunct = "";
String endPunct = "";

for (int c = 0; c < s.length(); c++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < punct.length(); i++) {
      if (s.charAt(c) == punct.charAt(i)) {
         startPunct = startPunct + s.charAt(c);
      }
   }  
}
```

If needed, this is the basic idea of how I print my translated word:

```java
s = s.substring(i) + s.substring(0, i) + "ay";

return s;
```

So the question is, how do I preserve the punctuation so that it appears in the beginning and at the end of the translated word (recursion preferably but regex is fine)?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems lend themselves to recursion but your task is not one of them, in my opinion. Hence the below code uses [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Notes after the code.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Converts an English word into pig latin. Algorithm follows.
 * <ol>
 * <li>All initial consonants are moved to the end of the word and <i>ay</i> is appended, for
 * example <i>what</i> becomes <i>atwhay</i></li>
 * <li>For words that begin with a vowel, <i>way</i> is appended to the word for example <i>oh</i>
 * becomes <i>ohway</i>.</li>
 * </ol>
 * Additional stipulations include the following.
 * <ol>
 * <li>Initial punctuation and terminal punctuation are unchanged in the converted word, for
 * example if the original word ends with a question mark then the converted word also ends with a
 * question mark meaning that <i>what?</i> becomes <i>atwhay?</i></li>
 * <li>Case sensitivity is preserved.</li> 
 * </ol>
 */
public class PigLatin {
    private static final String  VOWELS = "aeiou";

    private static int getIndexOfFirstVowelInWord(String word) {
        int index = -1;
        if (word != null  &&  !word.isBlank()) {
            word = word.strip();
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                if (VOWELS.indexOf(letters[i]) >= 0) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * First method invoked when this class launched via <tt>java</tt> command. Recognizes a single
     * command argument which is the word to be converted into pig latin.
     * 
     * @param args - <tt>java</tt> command arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("ARGS: word");
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("Word: ^%s^%n", args[0]);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([!?\"'():;,.-]*)(\\w+[!?\"'():;,.-]*\\w+)([!?\"'():;,.-]*)$");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(args[0]);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String initial = matcher.group(1);
                String word = matcher.group(2);
                word = word.strip();
                String terminal = matcher.group(3);
                int index = getIndexOfFirstVowelInWord(word);
                if (index == 0) {
                    word += "way";
                }
                else {
                    String suffix = word.substring(0, index);
                    word = word.substring(index);
                    word += suffix;
                    word += "ay";
                }
                String result = initial + word + terminal;
                System.out.println("Result: " + result);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No match.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I test for punctuation which is commonly found in prose, including the following.

- exclamation mark
- question mark
- double quote
- single quote
- parentheses
- colon
- semi colon
- comma
- period
- dash

The regular expression contains three groups.

- First group is leading punctuation.
- Second group is actual word, which may contain embedded punctuation.
- Third group is trailing punctuation.

We only need to handle the second group. The handling algorithm is described in the class comments in the above code.

I tested the code for all the example words in your question and got your expected result for each word.